# Send email in linux from a Jar file

Tags: java, linux, email, jar

I have been trying to schedule a job in linux to run a runable jar file which is written in Java and it will send out emails.

First, I use command `Java -jar /usr/test/test.jar` to run the jar file. It works well and send out email to my gmail account.

Then I use crontab to schedule a job to run every 10 min. The code is `0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * java -jar /usr/test/test.jar`.

It didn't work as I expected. I didn't get any email in my gmail. But I check /var/spool/mail. I saw a new mail there.

My question is how can I receive the email in my gmail when schedule it as a job.

Update:
I watch through the email in /var/spool/mail. This is one of the messages:

From test@test.job  Tue Apr 14 10:10:01 2015

Return-Path: test@test.job

X-Original-To: test

Delivered-To: test@test.job

Received: by test.job (Postfix, from userid 1254)
        id B7D276B1E8D; Tue, 14 Apr 2015 10:10:01 -0600 (MDT)

From: "(Cron Daemon)" test@test.job

To: test@test.job

X-Cron-Env: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1254

X-Cron-Env: LANG=en_US.UTF-8

X-Cron-Env: SHELL=/bin/sh

X-Cron-Env: HOME=/home/test

X-Cron-Env: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin

X-Cron-Env: LOGNAME=test

X-Cron-Env: USER=test

Message-Id: 20150413195002.0E0356E778C@test.job
Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2015 13:50:02 -0600 (MDT)

/bin/sh: java: command not found

Any idea what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect your path is not properly set, cron runs in its own bash profile, try with full path for `java`

Comment: On a side note, you could just use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor--) and keep Java running in the background instead of calling it every 10 minutes.

Comment: @JigarJoshi The path I specified is the full path of the jar file. And it works correct if I don't schedule it as a job.

Comment: I mean full path of executable java

Comment: @JigarJoshi Yes. After I specify the full path of executable jave. It works perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I will add it as answer you could mark it as accepted for others reference

Comment: @Powerlord Thanks for your suggestion. I also try this method, it works fine right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your path is not properly set, cron runs in its own bash profile, try with full path for `java`

Answer (score 0):

Has crontab run without loading you current profile, most probably your jar execution is missing some global variables/settings.
Instead of just calling you jar you should previously load your current profile has follows and eventually save log for further analysis:

`0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * . ~/.profile; java -jar /usr/test/test.jar &>>/path/lo/log.log`